# Laplace Transformation

Tags: laplace-transform

I ended up with the following system of equations in the frequency domain:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}\{f\}(s)=\frac{\alpha (s \beta+ \gamma)}{(s \delta + \alpha+\gamma)(s\beta+\gamma)-\gamma \gamma}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}\{g\}(s)=\frac{\alpha \gamma}{(s \beta +\gamma)(s \delta + \alpha+\gamma)-\gamma \gamma}
\end{equation}

where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$ are constants.

I want to factorise them first so I can transform them back to the time domain.

Can anyone give a hint how to factorise the above equations?

Answer (score 1):

Those are transfer functions of a second order system and integrate as a product of $sin$, $cos$ and $exp$ or $sinh$, $cosh$ and $exp$.
You can start from this :
$$G(s)=\frac{\alpha\gamma}{s^2\delta\beta+s(\alpha\beta+\gamma\beta+\gamma\delta)+\gamma\alpha}$$
$$=\frac{\alpha\gamma}{(s\sqrt{\delta\beta}+\frac{1}{2}(\alpha\beta+\gamma\beta+\gamma\delta))^2-(\alpha\beta+\gamma\beta+\gamma\delta)^2+\gamma\alpha}$$
Still you need to have some information about the sign of $-(\alpha\beta+\gamma\beta+\gamma\delta)^2+\gamma\alpha$ to use a table of transforms.

If you have no clue about this term the idea to go further would be :
$$G(s)=\frac{\alpha\gamma/\delta\beta}{(s+\frac{1}{2}(\alpha\beta+\gamma\beta+\gamma\delta)/\sqrt{\delta\beta})^2-(\alpha\beta+\gamma\beta+\gamma\delta)^2/\delta\beta+\gamma\alpha/\delta\beta}$$
Then let $K=\alpha\gamma/\delta\beta$, $A=\frac{1}{2}(\alpha\beta+\gamma\beta+\gamma\delta)/\sqrt{\delta\beta}$, $\Omega=\sqrt{-(\alpha\beta+\gamma\beta+\gamma\delta)^2/\delta\beta+\gamma\alpha/\delta\beta}$

Note that you have the relation :
$$\Omega=\sqrt{K-4A^2}$$
 then :
$$G(s)=\frac{K}{(s+A)^2+\Omega^2}=\frac{K}{\Omega}\frac{\Omega}{(s+A)^2+\Omega^2}=\mathcal{L}\left[\frac{K}{\Omega}e^{-At}\sin(\Omega t)\cdot u(t)\right]$$
You just have to hope that $\Omega\in\mathbb{R}$ which corresponds to the nice condition $K-4A^2\geq 0$

Comment: I don't think I have information about that. We can't simplify this any further?

Comment: You can certainly simplify but you will have possibly complex expressions in the time domain (which can be transformed into $sin$, $cos$)

Answer (score 0):

Factor out the $\beta$ and $\delta$ from the denominator, then you will be left with something of the form $(s+a)(s+b) -c$. Try writing this as $(s-d)^2 - e$. (so I'm working towards 25 in [this](http://integral-table.com/downloads/LaplaceTable.pdf) table.)

Can you work it out from here?
You need to write out $(s+a)(s+b)$ and $(s-d)^2$ out and try to find $d$ and $e$ to get the trick done.

Comment: I can't see the table. The link doesn't seem to be working. Can you please explain it a little bit more. I still can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: You are trying to get to the form of transform of $\exp(at) \cosh(bt)$ and $\exp(at)\sinh(bt)$. Generally, when dealing with Laplace transforms it's a bad idea to go guns blazing and factorize your fraction to smaller parts. Try remembering the shape of sin & cos transforms as, those will come about often.

Comment: @user105627 I added other link to a Laplace table.

Comment: I thought that by factorising the above it will be possible to end up with something of the form $e^{at}-e^{bt}/a-b$ for the $g$.

Comment: You will... in the end. Factorizing is a long road usually. It's way more handy to rewrite in the form of cosh times exp. (note cosh is a sum of two exps itself!).

Comment: I'm trying to follow your steps. So you told me to write it first in the form $(s+a)(s+b)$. $\mathcal{L}\{f\}(s)=\frac{\alpha(s\beta+\gamma)}{\delta\beta(s+\frac{\alpha}{\delta}+\frac{\gamma}{\delta}) +(s+\frac{\gamma}{\beta})-\gamma \gamma}$. Then I have to rewrite the denominator in this form $(s-d)^2-e$?

Comment: So basically I ended up with what H.C. did before because if I rewrite it in that form I ended up with same thing as shown below but with $\delta \beta$ as a common factor. So how can I continue from there? I still didn't get it sorry

Comment: @user105627 You are almost there then! Look at the table I posted (24 and 25 from the top of my head.). What do you need to set your $a$ and $b$ to, to get exact same formula as in the table?

Comment: I ended up with this now $\frac{\alpha\beta(s+\frac{\gamma}{\beta})}{\delta\beta(s+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\alpha}{\delta}+\frac{\gamma}{\delta}+\frac{\gamma}{\beta}))^2-\frac{\alpha}{\delta}+\frac{\gamma}{\delta}+\frac{\gamma}{\beta})^2+\frac{\alpha\gamma}{\delta\beta}}$ So looking at the table (25) the $a$ in the numerator is different from the $a$ in the denominator. Is $k^2=(\frac{\alpha}{\delta}+\frac{\gamma}{\delta}+\frac{\gamma}{\beta})^2+\frac{\alpha\gamma}{\delta\beta}$?